# How can I create only one instance of a DataContext for multiple windows?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datacontext

So I have a WPF program in which I have a ViewModel and several windows. I usually add the DataContext for my ViewModel like this:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:PrintView x:Name="printerView"/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

But if I do it that way, I have the problem that multiple instances of the ViewModel are created, one instance for each window. Which means that if I change a property in one window, the same property of the other window  doesn't change.

Now I had done it in such a way that I define it in App.xaml like this:

```
<Application.Resources>

    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:PrintView x:Key="printView"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

And address in each window like this:

```
DataContext="{StaticResource printView}"
```

But now the problem is that I want to create the whole thing without the App.Xaml. Does anyone have any idea how I can create the same result without App.xaml? As well as without libraries.

I'm working with .NET Framework 4.8

**EDIT**

I have now implemented the solution from @mm8. However, it still doesn't seem to work. Everything works in the Xaml part and I have access to the properties. However, there are problems in the code behind, namely when I select a value in a window and save it in the property:

[SecondWindow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fopm.png)

And so save the selected value in the property:

```
SelectedItem="{Binding selected_printer, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

But I then want to access this changed value in the other window, whether like this:

```
 var vm = (ViewModel)this.DataContext;
 vm.selected_printer
```

or like this:

```
ApplicationService.Instance.PrintView.selected_printer
```

No matter how I try to access the previously changed property in the other window, the property doesn't update in the other window with the new value.

So this value:
[SecondWindow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fopm.png)
is not transferred to the other window and is not updated

My Selected Printer defined:

```
 private string _selected_printer;
    public string selected_printer
    {
        get
        {
            return _selected_printer;
        }
        set
        {
            _selected_printer = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(selected_printer));
        }
    }
```

My ViewModel defined:

```
  public class PrintView: INotifyPropertyChanged
```

My Property Changed Stuff:

```
 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

Comment: Why not set it when you create the window? `var window = new YourWindow { DataContext = YourDataContextInstance }; window.Show();`

Comment: Ok, I didn't even know this worked. But how do I then access this DataContext in the other window when I open the window like this?

Comment: If you're using a `static` instance of the class to share the `DataContext` across multiple windows, you'd just access that field/property.

Comment: Or just pass the current DataContext like `var newWindow = new ChildWindow { DataContext = DataContext };`. Using static members is widely considered an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `App.xaml` to be able to create global resources. You could create your own application-wide service class and set up your view model(s) there:

```
public sealed class ApplicationService
{
    private ApplicationService() { }

    public static ApplicationService Instance { get; } = new ApplicationService();

    public PrintView PrintView { get; } = new PrintView();
}
```

**Usage:**

```
DataContext="{Binding PrintView, Source={x:Static local:ApplicationService.Instance}}"
```

This is basically how a view-model locator works (assuming `PrintView` is actually a view model despite its name...)

Comment: Ok I did it now as you suggested. However, if I want to call my ViewModel datacontext like this in the code behind: var vm = (printView)this.DataContext; And then I change a property accordingly: vm.property = "New Value" , this property does not change in the other window.

Comment: If you want to reuse the same view model instance, return a single instance from the service, i.e. implement the property like this: `public PrintView PrintView {get;} = new PrintView();`

Comment: And then access it by `ApplicationService.Instance.PrintView`.

Comment: The thing is I have a combo box in one window and in that I bind a property to the selected item. However, PropertyChanged etc is called but if I then want to call the property like in your example, the property is always empty, no matter in which window.

Comment: What property is empty? Please provide an example of your issue instead of adding confusing comments.

Comment: I made an Edit for the Question, I hope this will help you to better understand my Question, if not I will try to improve it ( im sorry my English skills are not that good, thats why I need google Translate, thats why its confusing sometimes)

Comment: What's the value of `ApplicationService.Instance.PrintView.selected_printer`?

Comment: The Value is null

Comment: So how do you bind then? And how do you set the `DataContext` of that element?

Comment: I set the DataContext  in the Defintion Part of every Windows like that: DataContext="{Binding PrintView, Source={x:Static local:ApplicationService.Instance}}" like your Example. And my Selected Item is Binded like in my Edit shown. In my Code behind I try to get the Value of the Property with that: MessageBox.Show(ApplicationService.Instance.PrintView.selected_printer); But thats null every time

Comment: So how is the `PrintView` class and the `selected_printer` member defined?

Comment: I added it now to my Question

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in the setter of `selected_printer`, does it get hit when you select a new value?

Comment: If I place a breakpoint there, the setter is executed at the selected value from the combo box.

Comment: Oops. Check the updated implementation of the `PrintView` in my `ApplicationService` class: `public PrintView PrintView { get; } new PrintView();`. It should only create a single `PrintView`. See my edit.

Comment: When I change it like this I get the following errors on the last line (new PrintView):
Error CS0106 The "new" modifier is not valid for this element.

and:
Error CS1520 The method must have a return type. 

and the new ApplicationService() part gives me this error:
Error CS0121 The call does not clearly distinguish between the following methods or properties: "ApplicationService.ApplicationService()" and "ApplicationService.ApplicationService()"

Comment: I missed a `=`. See my new edit. It should be `public PrintView PrintView { get; } = new PrintView();`

Comment: I thank you so much that's totally working now. Thank you for taking the time to do this.

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry about the about the confustion :)