# WPF After ICommand INotifyPropertyChanged is called, but not updating UI [MVVM]

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged, propertychanged

When the `View` is initialized, their standard value "VM", definied in the `ViewModel`, is updated trough the `Model` and updated in the View. However, when the `ICommand` NavigationCommand is triggered, the code in the OnNavigationCommand method executes, and even the `OnPropertyChanged` (INotifyPropertyChanged) method is called in the `Model`. However, the textboxes in the UI still remains the same value: "VM". I have tried a lot, but can't seem to find the problem. Hope you can help.

**View**

```
<vw:View xmlns:cc="clr-namespace:HMI.CustomControl" xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" 
    x:Class="HMI.ZoneFView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:vw="http://inosoft.com/visiwin7"
    xmlns:main="clr-namespace:HMI.Views.MainRegion"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HMI" xmlns:dialogregion="clr-namespace:HMI.Views.DialogRegion" 
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         DataContext="{vw:AdapterBinding ViewModel}">
    
    <Viewbox>
        <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Width="140" Height="220.5">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="3"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="3"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="5" />
                <RowDefinition Height="5*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="5" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding theModel.VisibilityFFUView}" Margin="57,16,7,62" />
            <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding theModel.VisibilityFFUView}" Margin="57,48,7,30" />

        </Grid>
    </Viewbox>

</vw:View>
```

**View.cs**

```
using HMI.Views.MainRegion;
using VisiWin.ApplicationFramework;

namespace HMI
{
    [ExportView("ZoneFView")]
    public partial class ZoneFView : VisiWin.Controls.View
    {
        
        public ZoneFView()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
using System.Windows.Input;
using VisiWin.ApplicationFramework;
using VisiWin.Commands;

namespace HMI.Views.MainRegion
{
    [ExportAdapter("ViewModel")]
    [PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
    class ViewModel : AdapterBase
    {
        #region Constructor

        public Model Model { get; set; }

        public ViewModel()
        {

            // If the VisiWin system is not in the runtime, the VW7 functionalities cannot be accessed
            if (ApplicationService.IsInDesignMode)
            {
                return;
            }

            // Create the Action Commands
            this.NavigationCommand = new ActionCommand(OnNavigationCommand);

            Model = new Model()
            {
                VisibilityFFUView = "VM"
            };
        }

        #endregion

        #region CordisAdapterBase implementation

        // Called when the view on which this adapter is located as DataContext is loaded
        public override void OnViewAttached(IView view)
        {
            base.OnViewAttached(view);
        }

        public override void OnViewDetached(IView view)
        {
            base.OnViewDetached(view);
        }

        #endregion

        #region NavigationCommand - Command from the view into the ViewModel

        public ICommand NavigationCommand { get; set; }

        // NavigationCommand event call
        // Will be called if one of the buttons in the "AppbarView" view is clicked.
        // The command of the model is linked to the button via the Command property.
        private void OnNavigationCommand(object commandParameter)
        {
            if (commandParameter != null)
            {
                if (ApplicationService.IsInDesignMode) return;

               string strParameter = commandParameter.ToString();

                switch (strParameter)
                {
                    case "FFU":
                        Model.VisibilityFFUView = "Turn on";
                        break;
                    case "FFUswitch":
                        Model.VisibilityFFUView = "Turn off";
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(commandParameter));
            }
        }

        #endregion
        
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
using VisiWin.ApplicationFramework;

namespace HMI.Views.MainRegion
{
    [ExportAdapter("Model")]
    [PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
    public class Model : ObserverableObject
    {
        private string _visibilityFFUView;

        public string VisibilityFFUView
        {
            get { return _visibilityFFUView; }
            set
            {
                _visibilityFFUView = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ObserverableObject**

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace HMI.Views.MainRegion
{
    public class ObserverableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
I have added the NavigationView, and shifted both the DataContext of NavigationView and ZoneFView to XAML to reduce some code..

**NavigationView**

```
<vw:View xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" 
         x:Class="HMI.Views.Common.AppbarView" 
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:vw="http://inosoft.com/visiwin7" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HMI" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="200" d:DesignHeight="638"
         DataContext="{vw:AdapterBinding ViewModel}">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{DynamicResource AppbarBackgroundBrush}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="8" />

        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="{DynamicResource AccentBrush}" StrokeThickness="0" />
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <vw:NavigationRadioButton HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" RegionName="MainRegion" ViewName="HomeView" IsChecked="True" Style="{DynamicResource AppbarNavigationRadioButtonStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="52" Symbol="{DynamicResource appbar.tiles.nine}" LocalizableText="@Appbar.Dashboard" Margin="0,0,0,0" SymbolHorizontalAlignment="Left" />
            <vw:NavigationRadioButton HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" RegionName="MainRegion" ViewName="FFUnitsView" IsChecked="false" Style="{DynamicResource AppbarNavigationRadioButtonStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="52" Symbol="{DynamicResource appbar.interface.button}" LocalizableText="@Appbar.FFUnits" Margin="0,10,0,0" BorderThickness="1,1,0,1" CommandParameter="FFU" Command="{Binding NavigationCommand}">
            </vw:NavigationRadioButton>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>

</vw:View>
```

**Solution:**

Like Clemens said I did use two instances of my DataContext. Therefore, when I did updated my property

I found this post on how to solve this problem: [How can I create only one instance of a DataContext for multiple windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70928082/how-can-i-create-only-one-instance-of-a-datacontext-for-multiple-windows) Thanks for the input! Case closed.

Comment: Have you tried by using another property name than Model?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It makes no difference.

Comment: Your ViewModel is not public, why?

Comment: Where is the command invoked? Maybe in a different view model? The view model in the ZoneFView's DataContext doesn't seem to be accessible from outside the control - except by casting its DataContext - is that what you are doing?

Comment: @Clemens The command invoked in a NavigationView.xaml using a btn CommandParameter="FFU" Command="{Binding NavigationCommand}".

Comment: @McNets no particular reason, just changed it to public.

Comment: @Clemens I want to update the ViewModel data into the model, and then update the UI's textbox value.

Comment: Sure, but does the NavigationView use the same DataContext as the ZoneFView? I guess not.

Comment: @Clemens Thanks for your replies so far. Well, they do. Both have ViewModel as DataContext..

Comment: But not the same instance. It needs to be only one, not two.

Comment: @Clemens I will update my code. Give me a moment. I dont know what you mean with same instance.

Comment: @Clemens Because I declare the DataContext in both classes separately? I have got two instances, but needs to be the same actually?

Comment: @Clemens That makes sence, when I am debugging my propperty variable: I get two replies back. One of them have not changed, and the other is updated.

Comment: @Clemens You were right. I found a solution. See edit. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The usual solution would be to set the DataContext of a top-level parent element, e.g. Window, and let the child elements automatically inherit the DataContext value. You don't set any DataContexts explictity except that of the topmost element.

Comment: You may to change the mode for the TextBox bindings to Mode="Two Way" or add OnSourceChanged in the binding. I did not test it, but seeing the update depends on more than just the notification. Also be aware, that is your notification points to an object and the address of the object is not changed, you notification thinks there is no update.